# Put CloudWatch Events rule with CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to stop my EC2 instance everyday with CloudWatch Events.  On console, it works without any problems.  By reverse-engineering the configuration I have done with console, a series of commands which is equivalent to it seems to be the following:

```
aws events put-rule \
  --name stop-ec2-instance \
  --schedule-expression 'cron(0 13 * * ? *)' \
  --description "Stop EC2 instance everyday" \
  --role-arn arn:aws:iam::012345678901:role/AWS_Events_Actions_Execution

aws events put-targets \
  --rule stop-ec2-instance \
  --targets "[{ \
    \"Arn\": \"arn:aws:automation:ap-northeast-1:012345678901:action/EC2StopInstance/EC2StopInstance_stop-ec2-instance\", \
    \"Id\": \"EC2StopInstance_stop-ec2-instance\", \
    \"Input\": \"\\\"arn:aws:ec2:ap-northeast-1:012345678901:instance/i-01234567\\\"\" \
  }]"
```

.

However, this doesn't work because I get the following error at the first command:

```
A client error (ValidationException) occurred when calling the PutRule operation: Provided role 'arn:aws:iam::012345678901:role/AWS_Events_Actions_Execution' cannot be assumed by principal 'events.amazonaws.com'.
```

.

How can I put Amazon CloudWatch Events rule with CLI?

Comment: It should work without role.

Comment: @LuboSach The execution fails if I remove `--role-arn` from the first command.  In addition, if no role is needed to accomplish the task, what is the role "AWS permissions" requires in "Step 2: Configure rule details" on console?

Comment: People on AWS Forum will be hopefully able to help - https://forums.aws.amazon.com/

Answer (score 5):

The IAM Role you've created (i.e. `arn:aws:iam::012345678901:role/AWS_Events_Actions_Execution`) doesn't allow CloudWatch Events to assume it.

Go to the role in the IAM Console, and under the tab "Trust Relationships" make sure your `Statement` block includes `events.amazonaws.com` as an accepted Service that can assume the role (aka. `sts:AssumeRole` action). For example:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "events.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```